# Is there a way to view the final style applied to my application after all inclusions?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles

My current style is as below, and has a lot of includes. To debug, I want to find out the final element level items that is applied to my app. Is there a way to do it? thanks

```
<style name="Theme.Emgreen_actionbar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_emgreen_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Emgreen_actionbar</item>


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not includes, but references. IF you are using Eclipse, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click on hover the `@style/...` to go to where it links to.